# What GI issues need to diagnosed/treated early lest they cause permanent damage?

Tags: gastroenterology

What GI issues need to be diagnosed/treated early lest they cause permanent damage or become unrecoverable.  An example would colon cancer.

The question is about which possible diagnoses need to be crossed off the list before it is reasonable to take an alternative approach.

For example if colon cancer is a possible diagnosis, one would want testing asap to, hopefully, rule it out.

If CC were the only serious possible diagnosis, then after ruling it out priorities qualitatively change. It becomes reasonable switch to a less aggressive approach, such as the other extreme of simply giving the body time to heal itself.

Could waterborne infections, including *Giardia* and *Criptosporidium,* microscopic colitis and bile malabsorption result in permanent damage?

Comment: For problems with your account try to contact the staff (the address is probably in your e-mail). The conditions you subsequently listed (such as repeated waterborne infections) rarely cause permanent damage, but you can check my edited answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Gastrointestinal conditions that can be **acutely life-threatening** because of organ rupture, bleeding or sepsis if not diagnosed/treated early:

- Stomach ulcer, gallbladder inflammation, appendicitis, intestinal diverticles, [traumatic spleen rupture](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK525951/), antibiotic associated *Clostridium difficile* overgrowth with [toxic megacolon](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2999149/)
- [Esophageal varices](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/esophageal-varices-beyond-the-basics/print) or [hepatic encephalopathy](https://rarediseases.org/rare-diseases/hepatic-encephalopathy/) due to liver cirrhosis
- Intestinal hernia, severe constipation, ingestion of a foreign object **-->** [intestinal obstruction](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/intestinal-obstruction/symptoms-causes/syc-20351460)
- [Acute mesenteric ischemia](https://wjes.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13017-017-0150-5), for example, in a patient with heart arrhythmia in whom a blood clot dislodges from the heart and blocks an intestinal artery
- [Gastric ischemia](https://www.cghjournal.org/article/S1542-3565(13)01089-6/pdf) due to opioid overdose, pneumonia, acute alcoholic hepatitis, [cocaine overdose](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/19165/emergent-gastric-ischemia)

Gastrointestinal conditions that can result in **permanent damage** if not treated early:

- Gastric reflux **-->** [Barrett’s esophagus](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/digestive-diseases/barretts-esophagus/definition-facts), [laryngopharyngeal reflux](https://www.racgp.org.au/afp/2017/januaryfebruary/laryngopharyngeal-reflux-a-confounding-cause-of-aerodigestive-dysfunction/) **-->** damage of the vocal cords
- [Chemical (caustic) injuries](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3703178/) **-->** scars/stenosis in the throat, esophagus or stomach
- Repeated acute hepatitis (due to alcohol), cholecystitis (due to gallstones) and pancreatitis (due to alcohol, gallstones) **-->** often irreversible [chronic hepatitis](https://www.msdmanuals.com/home/liver-and-gallbladder-disorders/hepatitis/overview-of-chronic-hepatitis), [chronic cholecystitis](https://www.msdmanuals.com/professional/hepatic-and-biliary-disorders/gallbladder-and-bile-duct-disorders/chronic-cholecystitis) or [chronic pancreatitis](https://www.msdmanuals.com/professional/gastrointestinal-disorders/pancreatitis/chronic-pancreatitis)
- [Chronic *H pylori* infection of the stomach](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2952980/) **-->** gastric cancer
- Celiac disease, Crohn's disease **-->** malabsorption **-->** [osteoporosis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2950667/)
- [Inflammatory bowel disease](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/inflammatory-bowel-disease/symptoms-causes/syc-20353315) **-->** strictures, adhesions, fistulas, primary sclerosing cholangitis
- [Colorectal cancer](https://www.cancer.org/cancer/colon-rectal-cancer/about/what-is-colorectal-cancer.html) and other GI cancers **-->** metastases, partial organ removal often required
- Atherosclerosis of intestinal arteries **-->** [chronic mesenteric ischemia](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3036470/) **-->** partial intestinal necrosis
- Tapeworm infestation ([cysticercosis](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/cysticercosis/gen_info/faqs.html) or [echinococcosis](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/echinococcosis/disease.html)) **-->** cysts in various parts of the body (brain, muscles, liver)

---

**GI conditions that less likely result in permanent damage:**

- Food poisoning and other acute GI viral and bacterial infections
- Parasitic infections, such as *[giardiasis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3870550/)* and *[cryptosporidiasis](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/cryptosporidium/symptoms-causes/syc-20351870),* can become chronic, but the damage is rarely permanent
- Irritable bowel syndrome
- Food intolerances (lactose intolerance, fructose malabsorption) and allergies
- Benign tumors
- Hemorrhoids
- [Microscopic (lymphocitic, collagenous) colitis](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/microscopic-colitis/symptoms-causes/syc-20351478) triggered by certain drugs, celiac disease, infections, rheumatoid arthritis, psoriasis

Comment: I like your answer; however I think you could do the prioritisation a bit clearer. Thinks that kill quickly are blood loss and sepsis. This is why any perforation of bowels and the following peritonitis or rupture of blood vessels (oesophageal varicoses or spleen etc.) feel like they provide the most imminent danger.

Comment: @Narusan, I rearranged the whole thing a bit.